# What does mktime overflow with the parameter?

Tags: c, overflow, mktime

According to standard, `mktime` should perform normalisation - when you want to add a minute and a half to `struct tm`, you add 90 seconds to `tm_sec` and call `mktime`, ignoring its return value.

What I didn't find in the standard is if the parameter is normalised even if it cannot be represented in `time_t` (for example having the year set to 2100).

So, is this code safe?

```
struct tm future;
memset(&future, 0, sizeof(future));
future.tm_mon = 1;
future.tm_sec = 90;   //I want this to be normalised by mktime
future.tm_year = 200; //but this can cause troubles

mktime(&future);

//future.tm_sec should be 30
//future.tm_min should be 1
//future.tm_year should be still 200
```

Comment: Can't you just assign 200 to `tm_year` after calling `mktime`?

Comment: I don't think the year can be anything before 1900

Comment: K-ballo: because I would have to handle leap years (for example when adding few hours to 2008-02_28)

Comment: Trevor Arjeski: yes, but only on some platforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard has this to say about `mktime()`:

> **On successful completion**, the values of the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` components of the structure are set appropriately, and the
>   other components are set to represent the specified calendar time, but
>   with their values forced to the ranges indicated above; the final
>   value of `tm_mday` is not set until `tm_mon` and `tm_year` are
>   determined.

So you can only rely on the normalisation being performed if the function completed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the return value of `mktime`. **You should not ignore the return value from library functions!** (exception for `printf` and a (not so) few others).

If it returns `(time_t)-1` the result is not trustworthy.

See an example at http://codepad.org/KTZwUHt0

The same code on my computer prints

```
time_t is 64 bits long
normalized to 2100-01-31 T 00:01:30
```

Comment: I know that mktime will overflow in this case. The question is if the pointed structure contains normalised data - I don't see any logic problem for the normalisation.

Comment: [The Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) is very clear by explicitly avoiding to describe the behaviour in case `mktime` fails to complete the conversion: "7.23.2.3/2: ... On successful completion ...". So, I think, implementations are free to do whatever they want.